# Calculating numbers of week for a specific time period

Tags: r, dataframe, difftime

Hi I have this data frame which contains the start and end dates of healthcare services. It looks like this:

```
id <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D")
start_date <- c("2014-08-18", "2014-08-04", "2016-10-10", "2016-04-01", "2015-12-31")
end_date <- c("2018-09-01", "2019-09-22", "2016-10-18", "2016-05-01", "2016-04-08")

df <- data.frame(id, start_date, end_date)

  id    start_date     end_date
1  A    2014-08-18    2018-09-01
2  B    2014-08-04    2019-09-22
3  B    2016-10-10    2016-10-18
4  C    2016-04-01    2016-05-01
5  D    2015-12-31    2016-04-08
```

The IDs are not unique because people may had multiple services simultaneously. These services may spanned across many years. However, I would like to calculate numbers of weeks for each service within the financial year 2016, which starts at **2016-04-01** and ends at **2017-03-31**. The data frame that I would like to have is:

```
  id    start_date    end_date       wks_FY16
1  A    2014-08-18    2018-09-01        52
2  B    2014-08-04    2019-09-22        52
3  B    2016-10-10    2016-10-18         1
4  C    2016-04-01    2016-05-01         4
5  D    2015-12-31    2016-04-08         1
```

where "wks_FY16" represents financial year 2016.

I think `difftime` should be useful, but I don't know how to specify the period that I need. I will be really grateful for your help on this.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(across(start_date:end_date, as.Date), wks_FY16 = map2(start_date, end_date, ~  as.integer(difftime(pmin(.y, as.Date('2016-12-31')), pmax(as.Date('2016-01-01'), .x), units = 'weeks'))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the difference in 'weeks' using `difftime` after making corrections for the '2016' year

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(start_date:end_date, as.Date), 
   wks_FY16 = as.integer(difftime(pmin(end_date, 
    as.Date('2017-03-31')), pmax(as.Date('2016-04-01'),
     start_date), units = "weeks")))
```

Comment: @j1234 updated with vectorized option as `map2` is not needed